# Python reading large file and spliting after :

Tags: python, split

Based on this example of a line from a file

```
1:alpha:beta
```

I'm trying to get python to read the file in and then line by line print whats after the 2nd `':'`

```
import fileinput
#input file

x = fileinput.input('ids.txt')
strip_char = ":"

for line in x:
    strip_char.join(line.split(strip_char)[2:])
```

This produces no results, however from a console session on a single line it works fine

```
Python 2.7.3rc2 (default, Apr 22 2012, 22:35:38) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
data = '1:alpha:beta'
strip_char = ":"
strip_char.join(data.split(strip_char)[2:])
'beta'
```

What am i doing wrong please?  Thanks

Comment: Have you tried:
`print data.strip().split(":")[2:]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the data format given this will work:

```
 with open('data.txt') as inf:
    for line in inf:
        line = line.strip()
        line = line.split(':')
        print ':'.join(line[2:])
```

For `'1:alpha:beta'` the output would be `'beta'`

For `'1:alpha:beta:gamma'` the output would be `'beta:gamma'`  (Thanks for @JAB pointing this out)

Comment: I got the impression the desired output for a case like `'1:alpha:beta:gamma'` would be `'beta:gamma'`, which your method would not provide.

Comment: @JAB Thanks .. I changed my solution to work equally well for both types of input.

Comment: "and then line by line print whats after the 2nd ':'" seems fairly clear to me, but I suppose additional clarification isn't a bad thing.

Answer (score 1):

Values returned by functions aren't automatically sent to stdout in non-interactive mode, you have to explicitly print them.

So, for Python 2, use `print line.split(strip_char, 2)[2]`. If you ever use Python 3, it'll be `print(line.split(strip_char, 2)[2])`.

(Props to Jon Clements, I forgot you could limit how many times a string will be split.)

Comment: from the output, it's a `Python 2.7.3`

Answer (score 1):

If it's everything after the 2nd ':' as a string (which can include ':') then use the maxsplit option, eg:

```
line.split(':', 2)[2]
```

eg:

```
>>> d = '1:alpha:beta:charlie:delta'
>>> d.split(':', 2)
['1', 'alpha', 'beta:charlie:delta']
```

**This saves joining afterwards**

Comment: Nice, I forgot you could limit the number of splits. Doesn't exactly answer the actual question, though, which was about why the output wasn't printing to stdout/the command line when the code is run as a script.

Comment: @JAB indeed... I believe by the time I answered that had already been clarified though. So it was a kind of complementary answer to others, basically pointing out `str.join` wasn't the way to do it :)

Answer (score 0):

You get just 'beta' because join gives you a string:

```
data = '1:alpha:beta'
strip_char = ":"
strip_char.join(data.split(strip_char)[2:])
'beta'
```

Try this:

```
lines=[]
with open('filePath', 'r') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        lines.append(line.strip())

for line in lines: print line.split(':')[1:]
```